# Getting incomplete HTML source on url.openConnection()

Tags: java, html

I am trying to get HTML page source for a website. But I am not able to get some image links, which I think are populated dynamically on the webpage.

I am using java as:

```
url = new URL(firstLevelURL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

try ( // Read all the text returned by the server
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    // Read each line of "in" until done, adding each to "response"
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // str is one line of text readLine() strips newline characters


      //I am not able to get this image as it is loaded dynamically using javascript/ajax or something.
       if(str.contains("<img id=\"tileImage")) {
          response = str;
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

I tried using :
connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
But the page is still not loading completely

Is there any way to wait for page to load completely before fetching HTML source

Comment: "Populated dynamically" is another way of saying "they are not there, *period*". They will eventually pop up in the page displayed to the end user in a browser as a consequence of some logic that will be executed in-browser.